# Blob is not generating pdf correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a pdf generator service that makes a call to the backend to retrieve the data needed to make a pdf blob. For some reason, when the blob opens, Google Chrome (or any browser for that matter) states: "Failed to load PDF document." I receive no errors in the console and my preview headers show the data is getting stored in my front end values. I am getting 200's on my http.post as well. Below is my code.

**Blob code**

```
    angular.module( 'utilitiesServices' ).factory( 'pdfGenerator', ['$q', '$timeout', '$window', function ($q, $timeout, $window) {


var service = {};

/**
 * @memberof pdfGenerator
 * @description
 *  Generates a pdf from given data
 **/
function _print(data) {

    if (data !== null || data !== undefined) {

        var bytes = data

      var file = new Blob([bytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });


      $timeout(function () {
          //IE compatabilty
          if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {

              window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, 'report.pdf');

          }
          else {

              var objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
              $window.open(objectUrl);

          }

      });

  }

};

/**
* Print the pdf
* @param data
* @returns {*}
*/
service.generatePDF = function (data) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    deferred.resolve(

        _print(data)

    );

    return deferred.promise;

};

return service;
```

}]);

**Call to the backend to retrieve the PDF data**

```
service.prototype.getPDF = function (id) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        this.loading.GetPDF = true;

        $http.post('service/api/GetPdf', JSON.stringify(id), { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .then(function successCallback(response) {

                    return deferred.resolve(response);

                },
                function errorCallback(error) {

                    return deferred.reject(error);

                });

        return deferred.promise;

    };
```

**Front-end response and call to the http.post function**

```
    $scope.getPDF = function (id) {

        $scope.data.loading = true;                                // Show the loading graphic


        tracking.getPdf(id).then(function (data) {

            // Tell the user that the pdf data was succesfully retrieved
            ngToast.create({
                className: 'success',
                content: 'Success!'
            });

            pdfGenerator.generatePDF(data);                       // Create the pdf using the retrieved data

        }, function (error) {

            // Tell the user that there was an error getting data for the pdf
            ngToast.create({
                className: 'warning',
                content: 'Error',
                animation: 'slide'
            });

        }).finally(function () {
            $scope.data.loading = false;                        // Turn off the loading graphic
        });

    };
```

I have tried changing the blob type, double-checking my back-end code (which checks out and does send the correct data to the front-end), and stepped through each piece of code to make sure everything is grabbing the data it needs.

Another pair of eyes would help tremendously. Any additional information you all need, please let me know. This bug has been driving me crazy for the past couple of days.

Comment: `_print()` does not return anything, so what should `deferred.resolve(_print(data))` this here resolve to?

Comment: _print() returns the blob data to pdfGenerator.generatePDF(data);

Comment: Do you recommend something else to try on that portion of the code @Thomas?

Comment: changed the blob type to plain text to see what's getting outputted. It just states [object object]. Seems like the blob isn't decoding the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it.

```
            pdfGenerator.generatePDF(data);                       // Create the pdf using the retrieved data
```

needs to be:

```
            pdfGenerator.generatePDF(data.data);                       // Create the pdf using the retrieved data
```

so only the array buffer gets passed to the blob, nothing else.